# Follow up to Bizarre canvas position locked by setting initial value

Tags: canvas, target

I posted a question about bizarre thing trying to change style.top of canvas.

People kindly advised tidy-up of code, but this still leaves me one unanswered question:

its still the case that if I initialise the top or left positions of the canvas, it cant be moved. But it can if I never give it an initial value!

In this example: you click on a canvas and should be able to move it-
if style.top is given an initial value, it will stop canvas ever moving vertically
similarly style.left value will stop it ever moving horizontally

e.g. In the code below // comment out the top initial value, hence it will move vertically, but why??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <script>
  var n=0, canv, ct
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var i,offx=0,offy=0, n=0
  canv = document.createElement('canvas');
  canv.id = "C";
  canv.style.width = "100px";
  canv.style.height = "100px";
 //canv.style.top =  "50px"; commenting out line will let it move
  canv.style.left = "50px";
  canv.style.zIndex = 0;
  canv.style.position = "absolute";
  canv.style.border = "2px solid";
     
  body.appendChild(canv);
  ct = canv.getContext("2d");
    
  canv.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
      if (this.style.border == "2px solid"){
          this.style.border = "5px solid"
          offy=e.y-this.style.top
          offx=e.x-this.style.left
       }
       else{this.style.border = "2px solid"}
    });
    
    canv.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
       if (this.style.border != "2px solid"){
         this.style.top=e.y-offy+"px"
         this.style.left=e.x-offx+"px"
       }
    });
    
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because this.style.top is a string, ending in px, so you can't subtract it like that:

```
offy=e.y-this.style.top
```

I made a few changes so that it is not trying to subtract strings in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/k6wzrbx9/) fiddle.